# Angularjs v1.2.1 - ng-repeat animation - animation classes are not removed

Tags: angularjs, animation, angularjs-ng-repeat

I wrote a directive which displays a list of elements. After list change the old list moves to the left followed by the new one. To achieve this behavior use **ng-repeat** directive and css3 transitions. I noticed that animations classes(*ng-animate ng-enter ng-animate-start ng-animate-active ng-enter-active*) are not beeing removed after animation end and the old node ceated by ng-repeat loop is also not removed.

Example in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/gqRIIUJF55NNvlt9lqMz?p=preview

The problem occurs in **firefox**. Under chrome everything is fine.

I would be grateful if you tell me what I'm doing wrong, or if it is a angular issue.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the ng-animate/ng-animate-start... are removed since angularjs v1.2.0 so you don't need to use them, check the [docs](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.1/docs/api/ngAnimate) or this [example by kevin-smets](http://plnkr.co/edit/U1JK27T2s5nq727kygb4).

Comment: I don't use these classes. I've just copied all classed which left after animation end.

Comment: It's probably an AngularJS bug try reporting it as an AngularJS bug in the official repos.