# ngRepeat's animations don't work when using ngInclude on the same element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate, angularjs-ng-include

Test case: http://plnkr.co/edit/dsG3gxFomAK8Q15Xfouj?p=preview

The test case above is a list of data rendered with the `ng-repeat` directive, twice. Once without using `ng-include` and once using `ng-include`.

CSS transitions are setup for all three (*enter*, *leave* and *move*) animations supported by the `ng-repeat` directive. All three animations work fine when **not** using `ng-include`, but only the *enter* animation works when using `ng-include` to load the template of each item in the list.

I'm pretty sure this is a bug with `angular-animate` but not sure. I might be doing something wrong when using `ng-repeat` and `ng-include` combination. I tried digging in the `angular-animate` source code and fix the problem, but couldn't. All I figured (hopefully truly) is that the `ng-include` directive adds a comment node just above every item rendered by `ng-repeat` and this node is throwing off the `angular-animate`'s workings. This is also the only noticeable difference between the two implementations.

Please also note that all functionality works quite fine when no animations are set. But in the example using `ng-include`, not only are the animations (for moving items up or down) messed up, but the items don't even move.

Is this a bug? If so, is there a known workaround? I tried searching the angular.js's issues on github but couldn't find a workaround (The ones I found don't work). Thank you for any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

> but only the enter animation works when using ng-include to load the template of each item in the list.

I actually get inconsistent behaviour in Chrome. Sometimes the moving animations work.

> If so, is there a known workaround?

You could nest the ng-repeat-ed / ng-include-ed elements, so the directives are on different elements, so there shouldn't be any conflict, whatever the cause. Example at http://plnkr.co/edit/dVniIVUaGS8y7wHe7CuT?p=preview

Edit: fixed plnkr link.

Comment: Yes, that actually works. Though your plunker doesn't have the fixed version. As for the inconsistent behavior, yes, the animations sometimes appear to be working, but if you notice closely, the items didn't actually move, they are still where they started. Only the animation plays, the actual moving fails. Thank you very much.

Comment: Oops. I've fixed the plnkr link.

Comment: No problem. This has solved the problem I had, but is still only a workaround. I'd like to keep this question open for a while, for attention. Ideally, I should be able to use `ng-repeat` and `ng-include` on the same element, I couldn't find any docs saying otherwise. For now, your workaround works just fine. Thanks again.

Comment: I note that on the one with ng-repeat and ng-include on the same element, a number of the animation classes aren't removed at the end. This could mean this is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117511/angularjs-v1-2-1-ng-repeat-animation-animation-classes-are-not-removed